# The getChild of resource is not calling in twisted

Tags: python, http, twisted

I am not a kind of expert in python twisted, please help me out for my problem , 
the getChild  is not calling when I am trying the path `localhost:8888/dynamicchild`.
even put isLeaf as False in my resource .

as per my understanding when I tried `localhost:8888` it should return blue page of course it is happening  but when ever I tried `localhost:8888/somex` the statement          print " getChild called " should be printed on screen but now it is not happening

```
from twisted.web import resource 

from twisted.web import server 
from twisted.internet import reactor

class MyResource(resource.Resource):
    isLeaf=False
    def render(self,req):
        return "<body bgcolor='#00aacc' />"

    def getChild(self,path,request):
        print " getChild called "


r=resource.Resource()
r.putChild('',MyResource())
f=server.Site(r)
reactor.listenTCP(8888,f)
reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because it is the root Resource that you send to the server.Site constructor whose getChild method gets called.

Try something like this instead:

```
from twisted.web import resource 

from twisted.web import server 
from twisted.internet import reactor

class MyResource(resource.Resource):
    isLeaf=False

    def __init__(self, color='blue'):
        resource.Resource.__init__(self)
        self.color = color

    def render(self,req):
        return "<body bgcolor='%s' />" % self.color

    def getChild(self,path,request):
        return MyResource('blue' if path == '' else 'red')

f=server.Site(MyResource())
reactor.listenTCP(8888,f)
reactor.run()
```

Requesting '/' will now return blue background, and 'red' for everything else.

Comment: Could you please tell me what is the difference between previous example that I posted and this(which is in your answer ).Of course I found some changes in code but I would like to know what is going on there

Comment: The main difference is that now it is your custom resource instance installed as a server root. Previously it was an instance of the generic Resource class. That's the one way to actually get your *getChild* method called. The second change is for troubleshooting only - I removed the print statement in the *getChild* and returned new resource instance instead, only this time I set it up to render with a different background so you can see the difference between calling "/" and e.g. "/abc" in your browser.

Comment: One thing that you may have missed is that *getChild* doesn't work like *render*. *getChild* must return a new resource instance and it's that instance's *render* method which is used for returning text to the browser.

Comment: In this case how to provide the basic authentication system to this resource

Comment: Why getChild method was not called when I was using instance of generic Resource

Comment: It was actually called but on the instance of resource.Resource that you sent to the server.Site - that instance (the root resource) makes the beggining of the chain of resources that is responsible for looking up children. What you have done initially was you registered your resource (instance of the MyResource class) as a handler for the '' path segment available under the root. But when you called '/bla' it was the root resource that was responsible for finding who should handle this call (or delegating this responsibility). Your instance was not consulted because '/bla' is not under ''.

Comment: I think this link may help you understand what is happening: http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/web-in-60/static-dispatch.html.